# I am designing a function in JS for scrolling dynamic page how can I pass document as an argument?

Tags: karate

I am designing a JS function to achieve scrolling of dynamic page so I created a function in **Scroll.feature** as

```
@ignore
* def ScrollFunction()=
"""
function(document){
var height = document.body.scrollHeight
while(true){
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
var newHeight =  document.body.scrollHeight
if (newHeight === height) {
break;
}
height = newHeight ;
}
} 
"""
```

And From another feature file, I will call this function for scrolling, but how will I pass the document parameter to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you need to spend some time reading and understanding this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-vs-the-browser

Even your understanding of Karate functions needs clarity: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file

Now, `document` should *always* work as long as a `driver` has been initialized.

One hint is you can break up into pieces like this:

```
* def getHeight = function(){ return script("document.body.scrollHeight") }
```

And then you can use `getHeight()` in some other function. Also refer https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#function-composition

So please open a new question once you have tried again.